# Update Angular from 5 to latest

Tags: angular, npm

My company wants to update from the current v5 angular to latest, 12 or 13 I think.
I did a little research, I think the jump from 5 to 12-13 would be too large. What would be the best approach here? Should I update in parts? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/). It's a tool that will walk you through the breaking changes in each version.

Answer (score 1):

I've upgraded from version 4 to 12 last year.
It took almost one week.. But the issues I faced was not really related to Angular but to components that were not compatible with the new version.

And the other tricky part was the migration of the Rxjs library (moving toward the pipe operator).

I've also used the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: Did you through each version, like 4-5-6-…..12 or 1 shot from 4 to 12?

Comment: One-shot to the 12.. Of course, I had a lot of issues. Mainly related to the Rxjs. But I think in version 5 you already use Pipe operator..?